# Why can not all DateTime instances be deserialized from YAML?

Tags: ruby

```
require 'time'
require 'yaml'

date = DateTime.parse('22018-01-05')

serialized_date = YAML.dump(date) # => "--- !ruby/object:DateTime 22018-01-05 00:00:00.000000000 Z\n"

YAML.load(serialized_date) # => NoMethodError (undefined method `captures' for nil:NilClass)
```

The same happens for `Time` and `Date` serializes it as a `String`.

For context the date string is actually a bad string, the year should be 2018.

- ruby 2.6.0

Comment: ISO 8601 and YAML only define 4-digit years.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is because psych, in `ScalarScanner#parse_time` uses a [regex which expects a 4 digit year](https://github.com/ruby/psych/blob/master/lib/psych/scalar_scanner.rb#L113).

EDIT: I have since opened a [bug report](https://github.com/ruby/psych/issues/483) with the psych project.

Comment: Good catch! I daresay this may be worth filing a bug report on.

Comment: I wonder what the use-case is to store a date about 8k years in the future?

Comment: @spickermann No one will ever need more than 2 digits for a year, I mean 640K RAM, I mean 32bits for a timestamp, I mean four digits for a year, ... :)

Comment: Then again, when I learned one thing in my career then that there is a high chance that there will be companies still running Ruby 2.x apps in the years 10000.